# Reading a time cell in excel as exact text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, validation, npoi

I have a `time cell` in my excel sheet having a custom format `hh:mm`. While applying it in any formula it treats as numeric value which excel keeps for time cell.

> Is there any way to retrieve it as text ?

The purpose is if I entered  `10:78` in this time cell it automatically converts to `0.470833333` instead of triggering validation or converting into 11:18. I can set custom format only since i am generation this excel using `NPOI`

So if i am able to read `78` ican include the condition in the data validation formula.
I tried `MINUTE()` but it returns `18 instead of 78`

Am really stuck with this. Any help should give me a great relief.

Comment: In VBA you could create your own function which would do that for you. will such answer and code help you?

Comment: Since i am using `NPOI` i cant go with vba :(. I am generating this excel sheet using `NPOI`

Comment: Can you use [TimePicker](http://danielcurran.com/instructions/insert-a-drop-down-calendar-menu-in-excel-choose-a-date/) from user's side?

Comment: Time picker in excel? is it possible with out vba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format your cell as `Text`, so user input doesn't get converted.

Use custom validation with formula `=AND(VALUE(LEFT(A1;2))<24;MID(A1;3;1)=":";VALUE(RIGHT(A1;2))<60)` (example for cell <kbd>A1</kbd>)

However, if I were you I would prefer to disable data validation and allow Excel to correct inputted data.

Comment: now am getting error all times :(. i tried to use this in data validation

Comment: Did you changed `A1` in formula to other cells? Note that you can validate one cell using another!

Comment: `=IF(AND((VALUE(LEFT(E11,2))<24),(MID(E11,3,1)=":"),(VALUE(RIGHT(E11,2))<60)),E11,"")` this is the formula  generated from yours

Comment: the IF function didn't work for me but assuming E11 is a text-formatted cell (apply text format while it's empty) then the AND works OK on it's own, i.e. =AND(VALUE(LEFT(E11,2))<24,MID(E11,3,1)=":",VALUE(RIGHT(E11,2))<60) - note that that forces you to use a 2 digit hour also, e.g. 01:28 is OK but 1:28 is not

Comment: Why would you use that `IF` formula for validation? Validation expects `True` or `False`, not `E11` value neither empty string. In Excel doesn't matter your file format, `;` is used as function argument delimiter.

Comment: Any way i got my formula from your valuable answer. Thanks for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the time is in A1, and you mean to use this value on the sheet, or in a formula;

```
=text(A1,"hh:mm")
```

Comment: I tried . But it returns `11:18` i can't validate with that. I want what exactly entered like 10:78

Comment: If you're not trying to do maths, then put an apostrophe in before the number eg. '10:78   but this will mean you can't add numbers etc. How would excel know otherwise how to display it - should it be 10h 78 mins, 11hr 18mins, or 9hr 138mins...The standard way of reporting hours and minutes is if the minutes is over 60 it is one more hour

Comment: But the entry is by user, The actual problem is  i have a time cell which having some data validation and custome format of `hh:mm` but while entering a time like `10:78` the cell value converts to `0.470833333` instead of showing `11:18` or triggering a validation error